# React/Redux 401 Middleware

Tags: javascript, react.js, redux

I'm trying to create an API middleware which will react to every 401 response from the API. I've tried to search for possible solutions, but I'm kinda lost here.

I have created a special 401 response on server-side, which returns me a proper JSON with 401 status code and I basically process it in the middleware and always call for `RECEIVE_IS_AUTHENTICATED` action if such status is returned.

Small note, I understand this is nowhere near finished code, but I'm just wondering, If you guys think that terminating 401s like this is generally a good idea.

```
import { RECEIVE_IS_AUTHENTICATED } from '../constants/ActionTypes'

const BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

function callApi(endpoint) {

    let config = {}

    return fetch(BASE_URL + endpoint, config)
        .then(response =>
            response.json().then(json => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    if (response.status === 401) {
                        json.unauthorized = true;
                    }
                    return Promise.reject(json)
                }
                return json
            })
        )

}

export const CALL_API = Symbol('Call API')

export default store => next => action => {

    const callAPI = action[CALL_API]

    if (typeof callAPI === 'undefined') {
        return next(action)
    }

    let { endpoint, types } = callAPI

    const [ requestType, successType, errorType ] = types

    return callApi(endpoint).
        then(
            response => next({
                response,
                type: successType
            }),
            error => {
                if (error.unauthorized) {
                    return next({
                        type: RECEIVE_IS_AUTHENTICATED,
                        isAuthenticated: false,
                    })
                }

                return next({
                    error: error.message || 'Unknown API call error',
                    type: errorType
                })
            }
        )

}
```